# Ubuntu 20.04 and VMware Horizon client 2006

Tags: 20.04, vmware

VMware released new version of their fine Horizon client. It officially supports Ubuntu 20.04:

> Horizon Client for Linux 2006 has been tested and is supported on the following 64-bit operating systems if you use the installer provided by VMware:
>
> Ubuntu x64 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04"

Horizon client does not work in my HP Elitebook 850 G3 with Ubuntu 20.04, but it works perfectly on a virtual machine. I have VirtualBox running in this very same host, same version Ubuntu 20.04 running in virtual machine. Installation used graphicaluser interface, which refuses to work in bare metal Ubuntu.

All I get is a black screen (or window).

It seems to me, that if you have any other display adapter alongside with Intel GA Horizon client works.

There seems to be a problem with Python-GTK, but could somebody tell what?

There is an advice to install python-gtk2 but I get an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-gtk2.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Installing horizon client:**

Read the easy guide on their website. I assume you did, or found the information somewhere else.

The gtk2 package is used for interactive install. It does not affect how the client works.  As you might noticed the installation default to console after gtk2 was not found on your machine.

**Getting the client work:**

Add the missing libraries in your 20.04 installation as follows (Inspired by solutions given [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/etavgv/failures_installing_vmware_horizon_client/)).

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0

sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0

sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
```

The above was just enough for me until a recent software update. Today I read a comment  [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/641958) that hinted the solution to my recent problem. For completeness I leave the relevant comment below.

> "The problem is the CPU cannot support a instruction pshufb. Using a
> nowadays CPU could solve the problem. I think this piece of code may
> be related with non-H264 part Blast decoder. Perhaps enabling H264 or
> using PCoIP could help."

In my case my remote desktop does not support PCoIP and H264 decoding was enabled by default. I disabled it (out of desperation I confess!), and the client started working properly.

Click on file icon on the horizon client, and click Configure VMware Blast to get to where you can select the decoder.

Other Resources:
Where is the vmawre log on your machine? [Read this](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-7/7.2/com.vmware.horizon-client-agent.security.doc/GUID-19CB4C98-31E0-410A-A4E5-5CA5068C7104.html)

Comment: For me disabling h.264 as suggested by zesys made VMware horizon client work again, the image quality was terrible; however, after `sudo apt install intel-media-driver-non-free` h.264 worked without issues! (tested on a Lenovo ThinkPad 450s)